# Initialize Objects with classes parsed with argparser

Tags: python, argparse

I wrote a Machine Learning script which I want to control from the command line. I already parsed all the options like for example --optimize 400, to perform 400 iterations over a RandomizedSearchCV grid. 
However, I'm struggeling with one thing: I want to choose my estimator, for example GradientBoostingRegressor() or Lasso(), from the command line. I tried two things:

```
def cli()
    p = arg.ArgumentParser(description="Perform ML regression.")
    p.add_argument("-e","--estimator",default=Lasso(), help="Choose between Lasso() and GradientBoostingRegressor()")
return p.parse_args()
args = cli()
estimator = args.estimator
```

But when I try to open the program with:

```
python script.py -e GradientBoostingRegressor()
```

I get errors, because of the "()", and also without the (), because it gets interpreted as a string.

Another thing I tried is:

```
def cli()
    p = arg.ArgumentParser(description="Perform ML regression.")
    group = p.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument("-SVR", nargs='?', default = SVR(),
                   help="Choose Suppor Vector Regression")
group.add_argument("-GBR", nargs='?', default = GradientBoostingRegressor())
return p.parse_args()
args = cli()
```

But now I dont know how to access the estimator and also it seems like  when I call the programm like this:

```
python script.py -SVR
```

the namespace "args" holds SVR=None and GBR=GradientBoostingRegressor(default_GBR_options), which is exactly the opposite to what I want.

Ideally I could choose between -SVR and -GBR in the command line and the parser would pass it just like my other options and I could initialize an object like this:

```
estimator = args.estimator
```

I hope anybody has some information on how to do that. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please include the error messages in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments are always just strings. You need to parse the string to get a function which you can call.

```
import argparse

def Lasso():
    print("Lasso!")


def GradientBoostingRegressor():
    print("GradientBoostingRegressor!")


class GetEstimator(argparse.Action):
    estimators = {
            "Lasso": Lasso,
            "GBR": GradientBoostingRegressor,
            }
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.estimators[values])


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument( "-e", "--estimator", action=GetEstimator, default=Lasso, choices=GetEstimaor.estimators.keys())
args = p.parse_args()
args.estimator()
```

(This replaces a previous answer that used the `type` parameter to map a string argument to a function. I misunderstood how `type` and `choices` interact.)

Comment: I like this solution very much, since its easy to add additional estimators. However when I apply it I get an error:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

I think this is cause by the type=estimators.get part of the function but I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Hm, not sure what causes that error. Looks like you can work around it with `type=lambda s: estimators[s]`, though.

Comment: This workaround works only if you also set choices=estimators.values(). Other than that its great! Thank you.

Comment: `choices` should *absolutely* be `estimators.keys()`; you want the arguments to be the (string) keys of the `dict`, not the (function) values.

Comment: Well, when I tried to do it with estimator.keys() I got an error telling me, that my choices are "Lasso" and "GBR" but I already typed in my_program.py -e GBR. I figured that the lambda function intreprets the given key and compares the return value of that (for "GBR" this would be GradientBoostinRegressor()) to choices.

Comment: Ah, I never noticed this before: the type conversion happens *before* the choice validation. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

While @chepner's use of `type` is a nice use of `argparse`, the approach can be difficult to get right and understand.

As written it raises an error in the `add_argument` method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack50799294.py", line 18, in <module>
    p.add_argument("-e", "--estimator", type=estimators.get, default=Lasso, choices=estimators.keys())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1346, in add_argument
    type_func = self._registry_get('type', action.type, action.type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1288, in _registry_get
    return self._registries[registry_name].get(value, default)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

It's testing that the `type` parameter is either an item in the `registry`, or that it's a valid function.  I'm not sure why it's raising this error.

```
def mytype(astr):
    return estimators.get(astr)
```

works better in `type=mytype`.  But there's further level of difficulty - `choices` is the `keys()`, strings.  But `mytype` returns a class, producing an error like:

```
0942:~/mypy$ python3 stack50799294.py -e GBR
usage: stack50799294.py [-h] [-e {Lasso,GBR}]
stack50799294.py: error: argument -e/--estimator: invalid choice: <class '__main__.GradientBoostingRegressor'> (choose from 'Lasso', 'GBR')
```

To avoid those difficulties, I'd suggest separating the argument to class mapping. This should be easier to understand and to expand:

```
import argparse

class Lasso():pass
class GradientBoostingRegressor():pass

# Map an easy-to-type string to each function
estimators = {
  'Lasso': Lasso,
  'GBR': GradientBoostingRegressor
}

p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Perform ML regression.")
p.add_argument("-e", "--estimator", default='Lasso', choices=estimators.keys())

args = p.parse_args()

print(args)
estimator = estimators.get(args.estimator, None)
if estimator is not None:
    print(type(estimator()))
```

samples:

```
0946:~/mypy$ python3 stack50799294.py -e GBR
Namespace(estimator='GBR')
<class '__main__.GradientBoostingRegressor'>
0946:~/mypy$ python3 stack50799294.py 
Namespace(estimator='Lasso')
<class '__main__.Lasso'>
0946:~/mypy$ python3 stack50799294.py -e Lasso
Namespace(estimator='Lasso')
<class '__main__.Lasso'>
0946:~/mypy$ python3 stack50799294.py -e lasso
usage: stack50799294.py [-h] [-e {Lasso,GBR}]
stack50799294.py: error: argument -e/--estimator: invalid choice: 'lasso' (choose from 'Lasso', 'GBR')
```

### `const` parameter

You could use `store_const` to choose between 2 classes, a `default` and a `const`:

```
parser.add_argument('-e', action='store_const', default=Lasso(), const=GradientBoostingRegressor())
```

but that can't be generalized to more.  `nargs='?' provides a 3 way choice - default, const, and user provided.  But there's still the problem of converting the commandline string to a class object.

Subparsers, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands, shows how `set_defaults` can be used to set functions or classes.  But to use this you have to define a subparser for each choice.

In general it's better to start with the simple `argparse` approach, accepting strings and string choices, and doing the mapping after.  Using more `argparse` features can come later.

### `get` error

`@chepner's` error has something to do with how Python views the `d.get` method.  Even though it looks like a method, it's somehow seeing the `dict` rather than the method:

```
In [444]: d = {}
In [445]: d.get(d.get)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-445-c6d679ba4e8d> in <module>()
----> 1 d.get(d.get)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
In [446]: def foo(astr):
     ...:     return d.get(astr)
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [447]: d.get(foo)
```

That could be viewed as a basic python bug, or a argparse bug, but a user defined function or lambda is an easy work around.

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailes answer. I think the definitino of the mytype function together with choices=estimators.values() should work as well? I decided against the possibility of doing parsing and mapping sequentially because I plan on having the mapping function outside my main program, so the dictionary estimators is not known to my parsing function and my main function. So I would have to hand it over from main to parsingfunction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could separate input from functionality.
First collect the input from the user, then according to the input run the functionality that the user requested.

For example, if the user ran:

```
python script.py -e GradientBoostingRegressor
```

you would do:

```
if args.estimator == "GradientBoostingRegressor":
    do stuff...
```